# How to read data from multiple csv files for user_ids that exists only in first file and create one Pivot table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pivot-table

The Question is: Based on the user_id column, I want to get the values of rating and product_id columns. There can be multiple entries with the same user_id in the same file and other files too. 
 Following is the table with some data provided from the first file.

```
| product_id  | user_id         | user_name                                    | rating |
|-------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------------|--------|
|  B0009XRZ92 | A2JFZLAUG3YFQ7  |  Entropy Babe "EB"                           | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A22HGAAO8KZ2N3  |  R.   Metzelar                               | 5      |
|  B000067A8B |  A2NJO6YE954DBH |  Lawrance M. Bernabo                         | 4      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A3HE4MYMWK4AER |  Rebecca M. Eddy "Foster Mom and   Untbunny" | 5      |
|  B003A3R3ZY | A9A2PR663ED1V   |  Roger D. Goff                               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A2MRZDJF90JC1U  |  Suzanne K. Armstrong "Suzy Q"               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A2YNBDT3170PCR |  C.   O'Hern                                 | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A10VJ7BDVCPKEZ |  Carol S. Bottom                             | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  AAAQO894MG80B  |  Paul J. Michko                              | 5      |
|  B00067BBQE | A9A2PR663ED1V   |  Roger D. Goff                               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A31S5QUMFR8NH2  |  Dana L. Jordan "Mom of Twins"               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A2DS24DHXUH0GM |  Gaz    Rev(iewer)                           | 4      |
|  B00006AUMZ |  A2NJO6YE954DBH |  Lawrance M. Bernabo                         | 4      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A16FRHL2ZC7EUR |  M.   Claytor                                | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A3AV8R0A62PP1N  |  MARCUSHELBLINZ "mmmacman"                   | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A3QN84C38DE9FU |  Gillian M. Kratzer                          | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A36MLTLVQFEQYL |  Yossarian "alienated socialist"             | 5      |
|  B00006AUMD |  A2NJO6YE954DBH |  Lawrance M. Bernabo                         | 4      |
```

> What I want to do is:
>
> To take one user_id only from the first file and display the rating and product_id
>   columns value for that user for all the movies from all the files and if the
>   user didn't rate some movies then the record should be displayed with
>   the product_id value and rating as Nan and the whole process should be
>   repeated for all the users in the first file only.

By using the `pivot_table`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('LCM1.csv')
df_new=df.pivot_table(index='user_id',columns='product_id',values='rating').rename_axis(None,1)
print(df_new)

The result will be the following:
                     B000067A8B     B00006AUMD     B00006AUMZ     B00067BBQE   \
user_id                                                                         
  A10VJ7BDVCPKEZ             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A16FRHL2ZC7EUR             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A2DS24DHXUH0GM             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A2NJO6YE954DBH             4.0            4.0            4.0            NaN   
  A2YNBDT3170PCR             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A36MLTLVQFEQYL             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A3HE4MYMWK4AER             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A3QN84C38DE9FU             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  AAAQO894MG80B              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A22HGAAO8KZ2N3              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A2JFZLAUG3YFQ7              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A2MRZDJF90JC1U              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A31S5QUMFR8NH2              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A3AV8R0A62PP1N              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A9A2PR663ED1V               NaN            NaN            NaN            5.0   

                     B0009XRZ92     B003A3R3ZY   
user_id                                          
  A10VJ7BDVCPKEZ             5.0            NaN  
  A16FRHL2ZC7EUR             5.0            NaN  
  A2DS24DHXUH0GM             4.0            NaN  
  A2NJO6YE954DBH             NaN            NaN  
  A2YNBDT3170PCR             5.0            NaN  
  A36MLTLVQFEQYL             5.0            NaN  
  A3HE4MYMWK4AER             5.0            NaN  
  A3QN84C38DE9FU             5.0            NaN  
  AAAQO894MG80B              5.0            NaN  
 A22HGAAO8KZ2N3              5.0            NaN  
 A2JFZLAUG3YFQ7              5.0            NaN  
 A2MRZDJF90JC1U              5.0            NaN  
 A31S5QUMFR8NH2              5.0            NaN  
 A3AV8R0A62PP1N              5.0            NaN  
 A9A2PR663ED1V               NaN            5.0
```

> But What I want to do is to take user_id values from the only first
>   file and search for `product_id` and `rating` values in all files
>   against that `user_id`.

Hopefully, you've got my question and if any problem in understanding please comment below. Thanks

Comment: What are the contents of the other files? The current file already has user id, product id and the ratings. Give an example of another file.

Comment: The other file will have the same structure but what I want to do is, to take a user_id from the first file and check for its records in all the files and same should be done for all the user_id in the first file only. Hope you got it.

Comment: Is product id going to be different in different files? So, what you are asking is - first file has all the users you care about, but the rest of the files will have different product ids and corresponding ratings. ratings can be missing as well.

Comment: The result of reading from multiple files will be more number of columns and values against these columns

Comment: The first file has some user ids and some product ids. What I want to get all the Product ids and rating against first file users only from all the files.

Comment: @Learner yes u said right. The first file has all the users I am concerned about but those users can have records in other files too. So, I want to get all the records against only those users.

Comment: @Learner Please upvote the question if you think my question is logically valid. So, others see it as a good question and try to answer it. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Check if this meets your requirement.

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("user.txt", sep="|")
data2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

# Merge on user_id and product_id
masterDf = data1.merge(data2, how='inner', on=["user_id","product_id"])

masterDf['rating'] = masterDf.rating.astype(str).astype(int)
df_new=data.pivot_table(index='user_id',columns='product_id',values='rating').rename_axis(None,1)
df_new
```

The output will be:

[image]

Comment: How it's gonna work? because we are just reading only one CSV file and how its gonna read data from other files?

Comment: You will need to merge rating_update dataframe with the other files. My understanding of your requirement is you want to get the ratings information from first file and then rest of the information from other files. For that you can call merge and how='inner'

Comment: Nope I want to get the user_id from the first file and based on these user ids I want to find all the values of product and rating against these users ids either it in the first file or other files

Comment: Kindly provide a bit specific code? All files will have same column names. So how the code should be written

Comment: what on in the merge function does? if its working as a condition then it should not be just user_id?

Comment: on requires the columns on which you want to merge. This is inner merge so it will work as set intersection rule. I have added two columns for you: user id and product id

Comment: Well, I'm trying to do it using your code. these are some little errors. the column names have been changed somehow. Once it solves my query. I'm gonna upvote and accept your answer. I'll let you know. Please upvote my question if you think its valid